# Wiring Smart Switch to Always Be On and Power Switch

Tags: wiring, switch

When using an Insteon 6/8 scene switch with smart wifi lights like a Lifx/Hue, would like to program the on/off buttons to a scene to turn the smart light on and off via software. That I can do.

However, need to have the switch wired to always be on. If I plug the line directly to the load with a nut, the light would always be on, but then no power would be going to the switch, I need power to the switch.

Is it as simply as attaching the line from the switch to the line from the wall and to the load going to the light together? And then capping off the load wire coming from the switch? In theory that seems to make sense, but would that work?

And yes, if house ever sold, would need to rewire back, or if ever need to turn off power to the light would need to flip the power breaker downstairs.

To note, the switch has a ground wire and neutral wire, both which would leave hooked up as is. Also this is a one way switch in a house built in the past 10 years.

Comment: Yes just disconnect the wire connected to the red from the switch, and connect it under the same wire nut as the black of the switch.  This hardwires the load to on, and let’s you utilize your scene A button however you wish progmatically.

Comment: Great, thank's what I was hoping. If you put that as an official answer here, will mark as correct. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing weird about hardwiring lights to be always-on *in the LED age*.  You don't need to de-energize the socket to change the bulb because there is neither socket nor bulb.  A 6W LED costs $6/year to burn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

Move the load connected to the red wire of the switch to the same wirenut as the black from the switch.  Cap the red on the switch unused.

With that change the load is always on, Scene A can be used however you wish progmatically.